# Huge ID gaps in my Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a very weird problem with my Rails app
There is a huge ID gaps for new signed users, I added a screenshot for my Users IDs

Is there any reason for this to happen? I don't think that these gaps are caused by some users that got deleted. We didn't delete any users, and we don't have any de-activate functionality in our app

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saves are wrapped in a transaction. If a transaction is rolled back, while obviously no rows get persisted, neither auto increment (mysql) nor sequences (postgres, see the note next to `nextval` in the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-sequence.html)) are reset.

When this happens you'll get a gap in the ids generated.